# Compare if input string is in correct format

Tags: c#

Check if input string entered by user is in format like IIPIII, where I is integer number, any one digit number can be used on place of I and P is a character. 
Example if input is 32P125  it is valid string else N23P33 is invalid.

I tried using `string.Length` or `string.IndexOf("P")` but how to validate other integer values?

Comment: Fantastic. What have you tried so far? :-)

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, you should try to find a working solution. If you stuck with a particular problem, we like to help you. But by no means I´ll do your job of learning.

Comment: You could use a regular expression for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions

Comment: Check regex patterns

Comment: Alternatively you can `Int.TryParse` first 2 and last 3 chars and check if the symbol in between them is letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that 'P' has to matched literally -

```
      using System;
      using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

      public class Program
      {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string st1 = "32P125";
            string st2 = "N23P33";
            Regex rg = new Regex(@"\d{2}P\d{3}");
            // If 'P' is not to be matched literally, reeplace above line with below           one
            // Regex rg = new Regex(@"\d{2}[A-Za-z]\d{3}");
            Console.WriteLine(rg.IsMatch(st1));
            Console.WriteLine(rg.IsMatch(st2));
        }
      }
```

OUTPUT

`True`
`False`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure someone can offer a more succinct answer but pattern matching is the way to go.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


string test = "32P125";

// 2 integers followed by any upper cased letter, followed by 3 integers.
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}[A-Z]\d{3}", RegexOptions.ECMAScript); 
Match match = regex.Match(test);

if (match.Success)
{
    //// Valid string   
}
else
{
    //// Invalid string
}
```

Comment: `Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}[A-Z]\d{3}", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);` in case we don't want to match `"۰۱P۲۳۴"` (*Persian* or *Indian* digits are provided ); or `Regex regex = new Regex(@"[0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]{3}");`

Answer (score 0):

It can be encapsulated in one simple `if`:

```
string testString = "12P123";
if(
    // check if third number is letter
    Char.IsLetter(testString[2]) &&
    // if above succeeds, code proceeds to second condition (short-circuiting)
    // remove third character, after that it should be a valid number (only digits)
    int.TryParse(testString.Remove(2, 1), out int i)
) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage the usage of [`MaskedTextProvided`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.maskedtextprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2) over `Regex`.

Not only is this looking cleaner but it's also less error prone.

Sample code would look like the following:

```
    string Num = "12P123";

    MaskedTextProvider prov = new MaskedTextProvider("##P###");
    prov.Set(Num);

    var isValid = prov.MaskFull;

    if(isValid){

        string result = prov.ToDisplayString();     
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use simple [Regular expression](//regexone.com/references/csharp) for this kind of stuff.